# .bind() with event handlers

Tags: javascript, dom-events, function-binding

Assume I have the following simplified function.

```
var ex = document.getElementById('exampleElement'),
    data = {
        foo: 'Sample text'
    };

ex.addEventListener('click', function(evt, d) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    this.innerHTML = d.foo;
}.bind(ex, null, data));
```

I realise binding `ex` to `this` is somewhat redundant in this particular case, but how can I bind the `data` parameter and still keep the `event` argument from being destroyed?

I can't seem to find the answer anywhere.

Comment: What is this `d` parameter? You can't control how that function gets called. Why not use a closure?

Comment: d is data, as parameterized in the bind function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

> arg1, arg2, ...
>
> Arguments to **prepend** to arguments provided to the bound function when invoking the target function.

Which means that your curried value will come **before** the event object.   See this fiddle for an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5w4vnvof/

```
var clickme = document.querySelector("#clickme");

clickme.addEventListener("click", function(value, event) {
    var newDiv = document.createElement("div");
    newDiv.innerHTML = value + "<br/>" + event.target.toString();

    document.body.appendChild(newDiv);
}.bind(clickme, "curriedValue"));
```

Comment: No way! That solves everything for me. Thanks a lot for the research!